# Uso de método diffForHumans() en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, carbon

Tengo el siguiente registro en mi base de datos

```
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | nameUser | passwordUser | statusUser | created_at          | vidas |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
| 14 | delta    | secret       |          1 | 2019-01-02 04:27:59 |     1 |
+----+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Con ayuda del método `diffForHumans();` quiero mostrar el tiempo de registro desde que esta en el sistema, hasta el día de hoy, entonces hago

```
echo $d->nameUser." esta registrado desde hace: ".$d->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

Lo cual me devuelve en pantalla algo como lo siguiente

```
delta esta registrado desde hace: hace 1 semana
```

Pero una semana claramente no es la cantidad de tiempo exacta que ha pasado desde el 2 de enero del año 2019 hasta hoy 13 de enero del 2019, entonces lo que busco es que mas debo modificar para que la información que se me imprima sea exacta pues entre una fecha y otra existen casi 2 semanas de diferencia

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Al revisar las opciones del método `diffForHumans()` encontramos la solución a este problema:

```
 * @param Carbon|null $other
 * @param bool        $absolute removes time difference modifiers ago, after, etc
 * @param bool        $short    displays short format of time units
 * @param int         $parts    displays number of parts in the interval
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function diffForHumans($other = null, $absolute = false, $short = false, $parts = 1)
{
    $isNow = $other === null;
    $interval = array();

    $parts = min(6, max(1, (int) $parts));
    $count = 1;
```

El cuarto parámetro de entrada es el que ofrece la solución (`$parts`), y como podemos ver más adelante en el código, acepta valores entre 1 y 6.

**¿Qué es una «parte»?**

Es la cantidad de unidades de precisión que queremos que tenga la cantidad de tiempo que mostramos, por ejemplo si han pasado 2 horas, 30 minutos y 6 segundos, si ponemos 2 como cuarto parámetro de diffForHumans, nos mostrará «2 horas y 30 minutos».

En la documentación de Carbon también aparece explicado:

> You may pass a number between 1 and 6 as a 4th parameter to get the difference in multiple parts (more precise diff) : `diffForHumans($other, CarbonInterface::DIFF_RELATIVE_AUTO, false, 4)`.

Ver https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

En la documentación también se dice que el primer y cuarto parámetro se pueden intercambiar, sin embargo no lo he probado.

---

Supongamos que quieres mostrar entonces semanas, días y horas de precisión, entonces utilizarías 3 como valor de `$parts`, algo así:

```
$d->created_at->diffForHumans(null, false, false, 3);
```

En caso que haya transcurrido menos de una semana, tendrás que preparar una lógica para que dicho número sea 2 y no 3.