# Obtengo diferentes fechas con Carbon

Tags: php, carbon

Tengo dos métodos, uno que me indica la fecha y otro el tiempo transcurrido, no me coinciden, es decir que una no devuelve un resultado correcto (la segunda),  ¿por qué?

Para *2020-08-30 19:38:48* obtengo:

> "30 de agosto, 2020"
> "hace 1 mes"

Estos son los métodos:

```
public function getPublishedAtDate(): string
{
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    $datetime = $this->getRawOriginal('published_at');
    $carbonDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $datetime);

    $date = $carbonDate->day . ' de ' .
         $carbonDate->locale('es')->monthName . ', '
         . $carbonDate->year;

    return $date;
}

public function getPublishedSince(): string
{
    $datetime = $this->getRawOriginal('published_at');

    return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($datetime))
        ->diffForHumans();
}
```

*Nota: la llamada a `getRawOriginal()` retorna el dato para el campo 'published_at' de tipo *timestamp* en MySql para la tabla correspondiente al modelo actual.*

*Acabo de escribir los métodos, si hay sugerencias sobre los nombres también son bienvenidas.*

> **Editado:**

Si sustituyo el cuerpo de `getPublishedSince()` con la lógica del anterior, sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$datetime = $this->getRawOriginal('published_at');
$carbonDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $datetime);

return $carbonDate->diffForHumans();
```

***Nota:** la aplicación esta hecha en Laravel7, en "config/app.php" tengo el timezone:*

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo incorrecto, que diga *hace 1 mes*?

Comment: @A.Cedano, sí, creo que han pasado 2 meses y 23 días

Comment: Creo que [tienes la respuesta aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/229424/29967).

Comment: Con `return $carbonDate->diffForHumans(null, false, false, 3);` obtengo: *hace 1 mes 3 semanas 17 horas*. @A.Cedano, ese hilo soluciona mi problema o me encamina, hay que escribir un método para tener en cuenta los periodos de tiempo trascurridos. Por ejemplo, no me interesan las horas en este caso, pero si los años...

Comment: Realmente nunca he usado Carbon, tampoco uso Laravel (toda mi programación es en PHP puro). Pero supongo que sí, que podrías manejar esa lógica modificando tu método. No sé si @Shaz u otro usuario experimentado en Laravel/Carbon pueda orientarte sobre otras posibles alternativas.

Comment: @BetaM sí, ya había enlazado A.Cedano ese hilo.